# ユーザが閲覧中ページに、ユーザのプライベートな情報を埋め込むことはできますか?

Tags: chrome-extension

ChromeExtensionのContentScriptを用いて、ある情報を閲覧中ページのHTMLに書きこんだ時、サーバ管理者はこれを見ることが可能という認識です。もし、サーバ管理者にも見られたくないプライベートな情報があって、これを含み得るUI要素をページ上に表示させたいと思った時、良い方法はありますか?

現状やむなくpopup内部に表示させていますが、使い勝手が良くないので避けたいと思っています。

Comment: 念の為の確認なのですが「ChromeExtensionのContentScriptを用いて、閲覧中ページのHTMLに書き込まれた情報」が主語ですか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。はい、合ってます。その意図で書きました。ご指摘踏まえて少し質問文を書き直してみました。